# Can I align variables in a string with echo and bash?

Tags: bash, shell, echo, tabbing

I want to do formatting using echo in shell scripting.

Here is a small code snippet which is giving me the problem:

```
echo -en "\rFileName    :   $filename   :    $index of $lines Completed"
```

The `$filename` is a string with varying length, and this is causing problem with formatting in the terminal. How can I overcome this?

Here's what I mean:

```
FileName :       a800_102 :    6 of 6 Completed
FileName :       ersf_1024    :    56 of 56 Completed
```

I would like to have a table format when I display it on the terminal.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [printf](http://ss64.com/bash/printf.html):

```
printf "\rFileName : %20s : %8d of %8d Completed" $filename $index $lines
```

Comment: Note that if this line is in a for loop, you need to add newline symbol "\n" after the word "Completed", or it will print only one line.